# VNET Peering Latency

Tags: latency, azure-networking

I’m running a mission critical global three-tier-application (App, IIS & SQL Virtual machines) on same region (Central US), right now, some of the European users are suffering poor performance. I’ve decided to deploy IIS server at their regions (France Central & West India). In order to provide better performance I’ve set up VNET Peering to short the latency between regions, but still when testing (ping or psping) I’m getting 108ms and 116ms~. How can I solve this latency issue? All of my resources on Azure.
Thanks.

Comment: Instrument your application to find out what is slow. What is the typical end user response time in those geographies? How much of that latency is from each of your tiers?  Azure Monitor might help, but is only one product in this space.